# Using credentials for access control in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, webclient, defaultnetworkcredentials

I have a SOAP -> web service structure, using C#.  I have IIS - windows authentication turned on so I am adding the DefaultNetworkCredentials to the ClientCredentials in my service instance.  I am able to access the web service using these credentials.  This is not the problem.

I would like to restrict access to certain information contained within the web service, depending on the user that is trying to access this service.  I do not know how I can gain any user information from the Credentials by passing the Credentials as a parameter, or by any other means.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the Windows authentication will determine if they can access the actual .asmx file in IIS.

You can use HttpContext.Current.User within your web service code to determine the currently logged on user's name as well (and then validate permission to perform action from there).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Aaron.  Yes what you said is perfect, however I need to know who the user is on the web service side.  I believe that passing the user name in as a parameter as plain text, or even encrypted data, can be easily spoofed and thereby exploiting my web service.   

Do you know of anyway that this can be done without the possibility of spoofing the username?  Or is there a more elegant solution?

NOTE:  I do not have a network, or security background.

Comment: edited my answer to be more succinct.  HttpContext.Current.User in conjunction with Windows authentication should not be spoof-able, if setup correctly.  You'll want to disable any other authentication methods in your web.config, or in IIS.